# How to configure nuxt-i18n for static assets files?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt-i18n

Please note, I have some js files included as follows, from the root "static" directory.

```
head: {
script: [{
    type: 'text/javascript',
    src: 'js/jquery.min.js',
    body: true
  },
  {
    type: 'text/javascript',
    src: 'js/bootstrap.min.js',
    body: true
  },
  {
    type: 'text/javascript',
    src: 'js/slick.min.js',
    body: true
  },
  {
    type: 'text/javascript',
    src: 'js/script.js',
    body: true
  }
]},
```

configured i18n as follows

```
i18n: {
    locales: [{
        code: 'en',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en-US.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'ar',
        name: 'Arabic',
        file: 'ar-AR.js'
      }
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'en'
    }
  },
```

Using en there is no issue with loading my js file, but when I switch from en to ar, browser console gives me the following error for all included files from the static directory.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ar/js/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how this is even working when set to English, but if you have `langDir: 'lang/'`, your files should be at the root of the project into a `lang` directory (at the same level as of the `package.json`, `nuxt.config.js` etc).

I'm not even sure what even is the first snippet.

Here is my `nuxt-i18n` config

```js
[
  'nuxt-i18n',
  {
    defaultLocale: FRENCH_LOCALE,
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'detected_locale',
      fallbackLocale: FRENCH_LOCALE,
    },
    strategy: 'no_prefix',
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: FRENCH_LOCALE,
      silentFallbackWarn: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      silentTranslationWarn: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      warnHtmlInMessage: 'error',
      escapeParameterHtml: true,
    },
    vueI18nLoader: true,
    vuex: {
      syncLocale: true,
      // syncMessages: true,
      syncRouteParams: false,
    },
    lazy: true, // not really working: https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module/issues/905
    langDir: 'locales/',
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        file: 'en.json',
        iso: 'en',
      },
      {
        code: 'fr',
        file: 'fr.json',
        iso: 'fr',
      },
    ],
  },
],
```

With my i18n files located at `/locales` at the root level.
[image]

PS: I'm not sure why you do have your files publicly available in the `static` folder. Any specific reason ?

---

EDIT to answer some questions in the comments.

[`static` directory](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/static/) is used to share some public files, that can be accessed by search engines, some favicons and alike. They are **not** used to load any kind of script.

Packages like Boostrap and alike, can be access via the official [modules way](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/modules), here is an example in the official docs: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#nuxtjs-module. This is aimed for some quick and simple setup of some packages for Nuxt.

If you want to add packages to your whole app, you can load script directly in the [`head-script`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo/#external-resources). This is usually not the recommended/official way and it should **NOT** be used to load some library from a CDN (especially `jQuery`, in a Nuxt app).

---

Of course, all of the 3 paragraphs above are **totally** unrelated on how to configure `nuxt-i18n` locales, just to be clear.

Comment: If this is not the way to load local scripts, please suggest. How should I load them?

Comment: I pretty much gave you my setup. So you can follow my answer. On top of that, you do have the documentation here: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/ And at the end, it also depends on what you want to do on your side.

Comment: No, I am asking for static folder files, I couldn't find another way to load js files. Do you know the better way? Please share.

Comment: So, what are we talking about here ? How to load some jQuery, bootstrap files or how to configure `nuxt-i18n` ? The question is asking 2 things at the same time ??

Comment: please check at the end of your answer you asked me that, why I am putting my files publicly. That's why I am asking this separate thing.

Comment: At this point, your question should be flagged as `needs improvement > needs more focus` because it is asking several things at the same time. Still, I've edited my answer but I will heavily appreciate if you focus on only one question. You can always make a new question for additional information on the others, no issues with that.

Comment: I have found the answer please check https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module/issues/1086

Comment: I'm still not sure of what is your actual question tbh. The answer provided here is working too, even if I'm not sure on how this is related to `nuxt-i18n` nor I do think this is a good practice at all. But hey, if your solution works, it's nice !

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your tips, especially the security one. I am still curious if I have some old-school theme written with many js-script files, how should I include them into the NuxtJs app?

Comment: Depends, classic `import from`, put it into [plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/) or maybe even in a mixin.